# Taquito does not originate or interact with test net contracts

Tags: taquito

I can't get Taquito (version 14.0.0) to write to the blockchain. Below is a minimal (typescript, macos) example to originate a trivial contract on the ghostnet. It gets stuck waiting at the `await result.contract()` line. There is no error, and the operation hash does not show up in ghostnet.tzkt.io.

```
import * as t from "@taquito/taquito";
import * as s from "@taquito/signer";


//
// get the private key generated with 
//    `tezos-client --endpoint https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.xyz gen keys jeff`
//
import * as fs from 'fs';
const secretKeys = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(process.env['HOME'] + '/.tezos-client/secret_keys', 'utf-8')) as {name: string, value: string}[];
const adminSecretKey = secretKeys.find((k) => k.name == 'jeff')
  .value.replace('unencrypted:', '');

/**
 * Originate a trivial contract
 */
async function main() {


  const SAMPLE_CONTRACT = `{ parameter int ; storage int ; code { CAR ; NIL operation ; PAIR } }`;
  const SAMPLE_STORAGE = `3`;
    
  
  const RPC_URL = `https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.xyz`;
  // const RPC_URL = `https://ghostnet.tezos.marigold.dev`;
  // const RPC_URL = `https://kathmandunet.tezos.marigold.dev/`;

  const Tezos = new t.TezosToolkit(RPC_URL);
  s.importKey(Tezos, adminSecretKey);
  
  console.log('originating...');
  const result = await Tezos.wallet.originate({
    code: SAMPLE_CONTRACT,
    init: SAMPLE_STORAGE,
    gasLimit: 100000,
    fee: 1,
  }).send();

  console.log('orgination posted. awaiting contract address', result.opHash)
  const contract = await result.contract();
  console.log('contract address', contract.address);

  return;
}

main().catch(e => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

I can successfully originate the same contract using tezos-client using command

```
tezos-client --endpoint "https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.xyz" \
                originate contract trivial_1 \
                transferring 1 from jeff \
                running '{ parameter int ; storage int ; code { CAR ; NIL operation ; PAIR } }' \
                --init '37' --burn-cap .7
```

Things I tried:

- different RPC endpoints (commented out in code) — no luck
- ensure user `jeff` has tez from the faucet bot — there's 100 tez in that wallet
- different contract code — same result
- waiting for over an hour
- Using Taquito to interact with a contract originated with `tezos-client` — Taquito gets stuck awaiting confirmation and the operation does not appear on TzKt

Things I have not tried:

- anything on the mainnet

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you remove the gas limit and fee entries:

console.log('originating...');
const result = await Tezos.wallet.originate({
code: SAMPLE_CONTRACT,
init: SAMPLE_STORAGE,
}).send();

...

orgination posted. awaiting contract address ooiEd9mDH8qijqEBGvJhQMPp1vgmLkWMCcbroYEpi1AUfEJgD5r
contract address KT1ShxcET6VnBN2qHGTggyi77vHVBPU3e6Fc

Comment: thanks, that did work. Do you have any idea why having those values could cause the script to fail?

Comment: We get the same condition with the Test Dapp we use when there is a large gas limit. It may be something with Beacon. I am not sure.